# TextClock render problem in layout preview

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, build.gradle

When i created TextClock widget in layout Android Studio layout preview cahsed and didn't show the changes. But on debug devise widget work perfectly. If I commented it layout preview work successfuly. Another PC Android Studio work successfuly and show TextClock.

Error Layout preview

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:2263)
at android.widget.TextClock.registerObserver(TextClock.java:626)
at android.widget.TextClock.onAttachedToWindow(TextClock.java:545)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:19575)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:355)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:404)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:657)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:788)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

TextClock XML code

```
<TextClock
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:format24Hour="dd.MMMyyyy, HH:mm"
            android:format12Hour="dd.MMM.yyyy, hh:mm a"
            android:textColor="#d0ffffff"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Changing `minSdkVersion` to 17 and creating layout v17 didn't give any results.
Problem found in Android Studio 3.6, 3.6.1 and 4.0

Comment: I'd report it to the AndroidStudio team as a bug

Answer (score 10):

Comment your TextClock and refresh your preview, and then uncomment your TextClock.
This will fix your issue.

I encountered this problem when I upgraded to AS 3.6.1

Comment: same thing happened to me - commenting out real quick and removing the comment right afterwards automatically refreshed the layout and all is well

Comment: Yeah!, It's strange, maybe a potential bug in new AS. Hopefully will be fixed in the next iteration.

Comment: Refresh and comment/uncomment needed do everytime i achange something in layout.

Comment: Keep your text clock commented or replace it with other widget like TextView until you are working on your layout and then again set it to TextClock when you're done

Comment: Thanks! I'm Using Android Studio 4.0 Preview and it is still happening but the comment and uncomment works!

Comment: This is not the proper solution. If we comment on the code for the view and then again for the testing on device we need to uncomment the code. Need some stable solution.

Comment: There's nothing you can do apart from this unless its resolved by the devs of Android Studio

Answer (score 5):

A fix/workraound is to create a subclass of `TextClock`
and add this into the created subclass:

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    try {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    } catch(Exception e)  {
    }
}
```

[Source](https://o7planning.org/en/12761/android-textclock-tutorial)

Comment: It works perfectly without having any rendering issues. Thank you @tgi_rxlph

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem; my workaround was to convert the TextClock to a TextView via rightclick -> convert view as TextClock extends TextView, then the Layout renders, and after the Layout rendered I converted it back to a TextClock.

It's an ugly workaround - not a fix (you have to repeat it after closing Android Studio) - but at least I can see the layout now.

I will report it to Android Studio as a bug and hopefully they fix it

Comment: I alredy sended bug report to Developers.

Comment: This bug is still not fixed in android studio 4.0.1... T_T