# My TextClock view is not showing in the design tab of android studio

Tags: java, android

I included a textClock in my XML file but it is not showing on the Design tab (and it keeps throwing up rendering error). if I remove the textClock view, the design tab will act normally, and anytime I add the textClock back, the problem returns.

Here is my Xml layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextClock
        android:id="@+id/textClock"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/darkPrimaryColorTeal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/menuContent">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/clockTag"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/cV"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/darkPrimaryColorTeal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wA"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/Alarm_View"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/darkPrimaryColorTeal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wF"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/facts_View"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/darkPrimaryColorTeal"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**here is my java code:**

```
package com.example.leau;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextClock;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextClock time = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.textClock);
        time.setText(time.is24HourModeEnabled() ?
                time.getFormat24Hour() : time.getFormat12Hour());
    }
```

**my build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.leau"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

I have tried changing the API Version preview from 29 to 19 and even 17 but it still shows the same error.

This is the rendering error it keeps showing:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:2263)
    at android.widget.TextClock.registerObserver(TextClock.java:626)
    at android.widget.TextClock.onAttachedToWindow(TextClock.java:545)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:19575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:335)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:373)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:678)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: This is a bug in Android Studio, and it already has been reported: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154169610

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TextClock render problem in layout preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565227/textclock-render-problem-in-layout-preview)